# Spot Undefined Behavior in this code snippet

Tags: python, c, cython, undefined-behavior

I'm 90% sure the bizarre result I'm seeing here is some kind of UB triggered by my code, however, I cannot find it:

```
cdef char** to_cstring_array(strings):
    cdef char** result = <char**>malloc(len(strings) * sizeof(char*))
    cdef bytes item
    nelements = len(strings)
    i = 0

    while i < nelements:
        s = str(strings[i]).encode("utf-8")
        item = s
        result[i] = item
        i += 1
    return result


cpdef object pykubectl_get(object items, object options=None):
    cdef size_t nargs = len(items);
    cdef bytes message
    cdef char** args = to_cstring_array(items);
    # message = args[0]
    # print("1 items encoded: {}".format(message))
    json_opts = json.dumps(options or {}).encode("utf-8")
    cdef char* opts = json_opts
    print("items: {}".format(items))
    message = args[0]
    print("2 items encoded: {}".format(message))
    cdef ResourceGet_return result = kubectl_get(
        opts,
        len(json_opts),
        <const char**>args,
        nargs
    )
    free(args)

    if result.r0.n == 0:
        message = result.r1.p
        raise Exception("kubectl failed: '{}'".format(message.decode("utf-8")))
    message = result.r0.p
    return json.loads(message.decode("utf-8"))
```

If I uncomment the lines assigning first argument to `message`, the contents of `args` changes.  My guess is that compiler is trying to optimize something here, and that it could be related to how memory allocation is done, but I cannot see any problems with it.  I also know that, in principle, I shouldn't need to cast to `const char**`, but I'm getting a warning for not casting, so I added it.  It changes nothing if I ignore the warning and don't cast.

I'm not posting the generated C code because it's huge... but if this will prove inevitable, I'll post it elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result[i] = item
```

This creates a pointer to the first element of your Python `bytes` object `item`. It does not cause `item` to be kept alive. As soon as `item` is freed (probably on the next iteration of the loop) then the pointer is immediately invalid.

You need to actually copy the memory - something like:

```
cdef char* item_as_charp
    # ....
    # then in the loop
    item_as_charp = <char*>malloc(sizeof(char)*len(item))
    memcpy(item_as_charp,item, len(item))
```

(You possibly need to use `len(item)+1` to give room for the null terminator)

You need to free this memory once you're done with it, of course

Comment: Yes, that was it!